# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Feature': Could not load file or assembly

Tags: event-receivers, feature-activation, troubleshooting

I have an `ItemAdding` event that I am trying to add to a custom content type (inherits from Document). During activation I get the following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Could not load
>   file or assembly 'ConnectToPMO.EventReceivers.ProjectDocumentEvents'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I am running SP2010 on my Windows dev machine (running VS2012 as admin). Here is the code in the `featureactivated` method:

```
        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog appLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        appLog.Source = "Connect To PMO";
        SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        string assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        appLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("AssemblyName: {0}", assemblyName));
        const string className = "ConnectToPMO.EventReceivers.ProjectDocumentEvents";
        SPContentType contentType = web.ContentTypes["Project Document"];
        appLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("Content Type: {0} ({1})", contentType.Name,contentType.Id));
        contentType.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding, className, assemblyName);
        contentType.Update();
        web.Dispose();
        site.Dispose();
    }
```

My event receiver code is as follows:

```
namespace ConnectToPMO.EventReceivers
{
    public class ProjectDocumentEvents : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);
            SPSite site = properties.Web.Site;
            string url = properties.RelativeWebUrl;
            string projId = Path.GetFileName(url);

            properties.AfterProperties["ContentType"] = "Project Document"; //properties.Web.ParentWeb.ContentTypes[ctId].Name;

            string SQL = "Select * from [PMO_BASE_DATA] where [Project_ID] ='" + projId + "';";
            DataSet ds = PMOHelperMethods.GetDataSet(site, "PMO", SQL);
            properties.AfterProperties["ProjectID"] = projId;
            properties.AfterProperties["ProjName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProjectName"].ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Through lots of searching, I have confirmed the following things:

- The WSP file is being properly deployed to the GAC
- Using ILDSAM I can open the WSP and within the dll and see 
  `ConnectToPMO.EventReceivers.ProjectDocumentEvents`
- I've added event receiver logging to validate that the doc type is correct as well as the assembly name
- I've reset IIS several times, exited VS, etc.

If anyone has any thoughts on what I may have missed or what I can try, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use the Fusion log to find out, which assembly could not be loaded. See this post for detail how it works: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/14/72912.aspx. Don't forget to restart your processes (run IISRESET, restart OWSTIMER and VS) before trying the activation again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, doing the things you suggested had no impact (I also rebooted). When I ran Fusion I had no error logs.

Comment: Does the directory you configured for Fusion logs (LogPath) exist? If not, Fusion won't auto-create it as far as I remember. If it does exist, you can configure Fusion to log all binding events (ForceLog), not only failures, just to be sure the logging is working as expected.